# How can I search a table column for a specific month, and then have excel output a list of names from a different column that match that month?

Tags: excel-formula

This is probably a very simple formula.

I have an employee database that looks like this:

[image: Employee Database]

I want to make a list of everyone who was hired in January (for example) in another workbook.

So I need to scan column 7 (Employees[Hired on]) of the table, and have excel output the employee's name from column 2 (Employees[First Name]) to the other workbook.

I'm assuming I can use variations of this same formula to gather my other data.

Comment: If you have office 365 you could use `MONTH()` as criteria nested inside of `FILTER()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need an intermidate column, because Excel can't filter by "modified value" (as far as I knew).

So, my solution is:

1. insert column between column E and F. The old columns after column F will be shift right by 1 column (F -> G, G -> H, and so on).
2. input F8 with `=MONTH(E8)`.
3. Copy F8's formula to below (I assume it is F26).
4. input with `=COUNTIFS(Work!F8:F26, 1)`. Note that `Work` in the range should be replaced with your work sheet name.

Step 1 to 3 may be done on another sheet. You should qualify sheet name like step 4.